# Error message in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to get a method to change a variable in another class. This is my code:

```
             /**
* Sets the tires on class Team to wet if currentRain is true
* 
* 
*/
public boolean setCurrentRain(boolean isItRaining)
{

   if (isItRaining = true)
  {
     Team.setCurrentTires("Wet");
  }

}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
    non-static method setCurrentTires(java.lang.String) 
    cannot be referenced from a static context
```

After looking at the question that mine is a duplicate of, I cannot see what the answer is as I am very new to Java and do not understand

Comment: Search on the error message for similar questions. Your solution is to not to call the setCurrentTires on the Team class, but rather on a Team instance, and not just *any* Team instance, but on the one of interest.

Comment: Also this is very wrong: `if (isItRaining = true)`. You are setting the boolean to true here. Instead simply do `if (isItRaining)`.